# How to use the XPath contains() function within document.evaluate()?

Tags: xml, dom, xpath, document.evaluate

I have this section of code which I've been using to filter out fields based on a searched name. The problem is that I need it to be a little forgiving in terms of what the user can type. So I have to use the `contains` function. I have gotten it working on other code snippets but am not sure how I can use it with the following:

```
var value = stylesheet.evaluate(
                               "//xsl:for-each[@select='book[author="contains(.,'containsSearchTerm')"']",
                               stylesheet, nsResolver,
                               XPathResult.ANY_UNORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
```

Sorry if the quotes/escaping is a little messed up. I don't have an IDE open to check my errors and I'm getting ready for work.

SO as might be able to see the containsSearchTerm is what I want to take the value of a form and process it using the `contains` function. How is this achieved?

Please be aware I'm pretty new to XML, XSLT and XPath in general so will need a little simplification if at all possible.

---

Reply to Michael Kay -

Hi, I'm trying to apply a searched term/word to the authors field within a XSLT table.
Yes you are right that is what I'm trying to do. Edit the stylesheet and apply the condition set within an input form. 
I've been using a prebuilt function thus far. Modifying as required. 
I can make the contain work externally if hard-coding the value for the input to search for. However I want to do it 'on-the-fly' as it were and am really just not sure how to get this working in the context I'm after.
What I actually have is the query being build within the form - specifying the field to search, operand and search term. But I don't want to search for whole strings because thats a little inflexible - so I wanted to use the contains function to allow search flexibility.

Thank you for you help

Comment: @mzjn, it seems, the OP is trying to look through an XSL stylesheet

Comment: How do I write a contains function in the place I want to write it to do a partial search of the terms I enter...?

Comment: @_lionysis: Even this isn't clear, but still would be an improvement if you edit your question. Also, explain what do you mean by "partial search". To learn more about the `contains()` function, read the W3C Spec here: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-contains . There are some good examples there.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're new to XML and XSLT, it would be nice to confirm that you aren't going down a rabbit-hole here. You are using XPath to search an XSLT stylesheet. That's a pretty advanced/ambitious thing to do, and it would be nice to know that it's something that makes sense in the context of your application. So what problem are you trying to solve?

As for the detail, I'm having to guess your intent by reverse-engineering syntactically-incorrect code, which is always difficult. I imagine you're probably looking for an xsl:for-each instruction whose select attribute has the general form

book[author = ....]

and you want to place some constraints on what "...." is, but beyond that I can't really tell what you are doing. Also, if you want to be 'forgiving', then you presumably want to allow whitespace in the places where whitespace can appear, etc. It might be that a regular expression match will meet your needs (regexes are available in XPath 2.0), but I really can't tell.

Answer (score 0):

**If the XSLT stylesheet against which you want to evaluate an XPath expression, contains this fragment**:

```
   <xsl:for-each select=
    "book[contains(author, ZZZZZ)]">

     <!-- Code here. -->
    </xsl:for-each>
```

**Then one XPath expression that selects this `xsl:for-each` element** (and may select other such elements if they exist) is:

```
//xsl:for-each
      [
       @select = 'book[contains(author, ZZZZZ)]'
      ]
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

When the following transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
  "//xsl:for-each
      [@select = 'book[contains(author, ZZZZZ)]'
      ]
  "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**is applied on this XML document**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
   <xsl:for-each select=
    "book[contains(author, ZZZZZ)]">

     <!-- Code here. -->
    </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**it selects the wanted element and outputs it as the result**:

```
<xsl:for-each xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" select="book[contains(author, ZZZZZ)]">

     <!-- Code here. -->
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can often achieve what you want using stylesheet parameters: look up xsl:param. If you want to supply more than just a search value as a parameter (for example if the number of search terms is variable), then sometimes the best solution is an xx:evaluate() call - many XSLT processors have an extension that allows an XPath expression supplied as a string to be dynamically constructed and evaluated. Finally, modifying the stylesheet before execution is an option: not the easiest, but sometimes the right answer. The simplest and most flexible way to locate the element that you want to modify is to give it an xml:id attribute:

```
<xsl:for-each select="...." xml:id="point-of-change">
  ...
</xsl:for-each>
```